# React handle async forms

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm using a form consisting of several FormControl objects (of react-bootstrap) and a custom form control of google places auto completion (with [react-geosuggest](https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) library), and I'm having problem with the fact that the geo-suggest returns values asynchronously.

1. When the user searches for a location, a side from the search value which I recieve immediately (synchronously), a callback in my code is called upon the retrieval of the LatLng of the address from the `react-geosuggest` component (because the component performs http request).
2. When a user clicks a Save button, I extract the state of the form, and then intend to send it to the server.

My problem is, how to "wait" for the callback of the `react-geosuggest` component with the LatLng info I need?

I came up with a solution but it doesnt feel quite elegant:

1. Allow the button component to register a callback to the form component.
2. Because I don't know if the user first search a location or insert some regular data values, callback will be called from two functions inside the form component:

   - From the callback func registered to `react-geosuggest` component (which will check that if the form is filled, call the save button's callback).
   - From componentDidUpdate, which will check that the form is filled and the location's callback has been called (i.e. we recieved the LatLng), and will call the save button's callback.
3. Now, the user can either click the save button before the callback has been called, or after it has been called. So I basically have to check this again in two places (in the callback: was the button clicked? and in the button click handler: was the callback called and data received?) and act accordingly.

Does anyone knows a better pattern to use, or surprisngly would like to support my method?

P.S I'm using Redux as well if it matters.

Comment: If you're using redux - set up a part of your state for this form and flag when the async is done, or just set up the bit of the state around that form to have whatever flags you need to make the correct decision? You can simplify the stuff you have to manage by letting redux do it for you... that's what it's there for :)

Comment: 1. The form output is not part of my UI, I know that putting data that's not UI-related and does not require rendering in a state is less recommended, but should reside in the class instance itself... 2. I can however save a flag in the state, and then handle all the logic in 'componentDidUpdate', checking that the form is filled & I have LatLng, and if yes, then call the save button's callback...

Comment: Thre is no need to bother with react lifecycle if you just control the form with redux, that doesnt mean you put the whole form in redux, just the parts you need control over.

Comment: dont know if its a good idea to put state of UI in redux... I think thats the point of UI components (as opposed to container components connected to react), of storing the state related to the UI

Comment: There are certainly different ways to take advantage of what redux offers a react app, however you are by no means confined to only using redux on your smart components. Infact, I have never seen a redux app yet that does not use its state to flush props into dumb components for use via ui or whatever you need to control the state. Redux is the state of your whole app in 1 store, I don't know why you would not use the state for what it's meant for unless, say you are using a credit card number (which you wouldn't store on the state itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the following way.
From your `react-geosuggest` callback, call the handleSubmit function.

In your form, add **`onChange`** function to the input fields and store the data in your react state.

On click of the submit button, disable your input fields and set this.state.submit to true.

Now in your handleSubmit function, do the following:

```
if (this.state.submit) {
  sendDataToServer(this.state)
}
else {
  this.handleSubmit()
}
```

This will ensure that the handleSubmit callback is called only from your `react-geosuggest` callback. Even if the async value arrives before the other form values(sync) i.e. the user clicks the submit button after the call to the location search, still the data won't be sent to the server until all the form data has been collected.

Comment: Just noticed the question date :P Nevermind, hope this helps someone else